# How to acces the DOM with my Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I've startet to write my first Chrome Extension. It should be fairly simple, however I can't manage to access the current tab's DOM.
What I'd like to do:
-access the dom
-look for an element like:\

```
<script type="application/json" id="ObjectId">
        {"name":"ObjectName"}
```

-extract ObjectName

Thanks

Comment: See [Documentation > Extensions > In depth: core concepts > Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/)